# business logic in admin panel

Tags: python, django, admin, crud

> I'm new with python and I create two models (Shoes and Order)
> I can add record by admin panel but I want each time that I add order record it's check weather the shoes are available or not! where should I put logic?

models:
[image]

Comment: Please use row code, instead of sprint screen, when you have some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options to do this:

A) On `pre_save` signal. In case you want to do check before you store an object in DB:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=OrderRecord)
def handler_order_check(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ...
```

B) On `post_save` signal or in `Molde.save` method, a check will be done after object is created:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=OrderRecord)
def handler_order_check(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ...
```

C) On admin form. In case you want to keep the check in admin side only, when objects created from f/e & shell will not have such check, [related docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin).

I would recommend using A, as it does the check every time you create (or update, depends on implementation) `OrderRecord`.